# Alter PostgreSQL sequence using Hibernate native sql query

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

My problem seems to be very simple but I have hard time resolving it.
I want to alter an PostgreSQL sequence using Hibernate via native sql query (other solutions are also welcomed) using next code:

```
    Query query = getSession()
        .createSQLQuery("ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH ?")
        .setInteger(0, 1);
    query.executeUpdate();
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Hibernate: 
    ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH ?
hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I'm aware, you cannot prepare that statement.

If hibernate allows it, emulate the prepared statement, instead of sending it to the server. If not, sanitize the variable and issue the final statement directly.

Alternatively, wrap it in a function with dynamic SQL:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: I know is not a good practice, but probably I will go with  the final statement directly, of course after sanitizing the input parameter.

Comment: Fwiw, altering a sequence is a bit weird too. :-)

Comment: Actually I perform some DBUnit testing, that's why I need it for.